# Covariance in Poisson Process

Tags: conditional-expectation, covariance, poisson-process

Let $\{N_T:t\geq 0\}$ a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda\geq0$ and $T\geq0$ independent random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Find $cov(T,N_T)$.

How may I compute $cov(T,N_T)$? May I set T=t and use conditional expectation? I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $cov(T,N_T)=E(TN_T)-E(T_N)E(N)=E(TE(N_T|T))-\mu\lambda T=E(T\lambda T)-\mu\lambda T$ - you can finish.

Answer (score 0):

$$ COV[T,N_T] = E[T * N_T] - E[T] E[N_T] $$

We first find some expected values to solve for this

$$ E[N_T] = E \left[ E[N_T|T] \right] = E[\lambda T] = \lambda E[T] $$

$$ E[T N_T] = E[E[T N_T|T]] = E[T \lambda T] = \lambda E[T^2] $$

Hence,

$$ COV[T,N_T] = \lambda E[T^2] - E[T] \lambda E[T] = \lambda ( E[T^2] - E[T]^2) = \lambda \sigma^2 $$